# How to display GMT or BST in PHP?

Tags: php, date, gmt

Seems to be a basic question but I can't find an answer other than "PHP handles it for you" and that isn't what I'm after.

Currently, if I `echo date_default_timezone_get();`  I get `Europe/London`
GREAT.

How can I tell if it is BST or GMT.

I need to display `Europe/London BST` or `Europe/London GMT` based on what it currently is at.

How can I reliably do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough - get the current time in `UTC` and compare it to the current time in `Europe/London`. If they differ, BST is in effect. If they're identical, it isn't.

Alternatively, use `date()`'s `O`, `P`, or `Z` parameters in essentially the same way - they should be `+0000`, `+00:00`, or `0` respectively if GMT is in effect. (`I` *might* work, too - I'm not sure if BST is technically considered "Daylight Savings Time"...)

Comment: Not sure why I didnt think of that..

Thanks makes sense!